# How do I deal with algebraic exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone introduce me to algebraic exponents, to the likes of $8^{x+1} = 4^x$ or $3^{2x-1} = 27$?

Google examples were a bit complicated for me, I'm hoping for some intuition here.

Comment: Do you know logarithms?

Comment: @Delimit: Do you mean $3^{2x-1}$ or $3^{2x} - 1$?

Comment: The first one, as someone kindly corrected.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $a^x = a^y$ then $x = y$, so if we can write both sides of our equation with the same base, we can forget about the exponentiation. Now note that the numbers $8$ and $4$ (or $3$ and $27$) are closely related, in particular, they can both be written as powers of the same base. Finally use the fact that $(a^x)^y = a^{xy}$.

Comment: Thanks I will try and work from that

Answer (score 0):

The formulas $a^b\cdot a^c=a^{b+c}$ and ${(a^{b})}^c=a^{bc}$ will get you pretty far. When you're dealing with equations like the ones you've mentioned it is useful to find a common base. So, to solve
$$
8^{x+1}=4^x
$$
it is useful to recognize that $8=2^3$ and $4=2^2$. Substituting these into our equation gives
$$
{(2^3)}^{x+1}={(2^2)}^x
$$
Using the identity ${(a^{b})}^c=a^{bc}$ then gives
$$
2^{3(x+1)}=2^{2x}
$$
from which we conclude that $3(x+1)=2x$. Solving for $x$ finally gives $x=-3$.

Can you apply a similar argument to solve the second equation? Once you're comfortable with these sorts of computations it will then be useful for you to learn about logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

These type of questions are very simple.You just have to make the bases of the exponents on both side of the equation equal and you are done with it as if $$a^n=a^m$$
$$\implies n=m$$In this case-
$$8^{x+1} = 4^x$$
$$\implies 2^{3(x+1)}=2^{2x}$$
$$\implies 3(x+1)=2x$$
$$\implies 3x+3=2x$$
$$\implies x=-3$$
Similarly you may proceed to solve the other equation by making the bases equal on both sides of the equation and you are done! 
You may refer this link to get much familiar with the laws of exponents-http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponent-laws.html

Comment: http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html is pretty good too